# Kак в таблице создать столбец с булевым типом?

Tags: sql, oracle

Подскажите, как можно при создании таблицы столбцу задать булевое значение?

К примеру 0 и 1. Насколько понимаю, в БД нет подобного типа данных.

Пробовала задать его так:

```
opal CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT opal CHECK (bool IN ('0','1')),
```

Но при запусксе в SQL Developer получаю ошибку.

Текст ошибки:

> Error report - ORA-00904: "BOOL": недопустимый идентификатор 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот две возможности создать колонку, которая может хранить булево значение (я субъективно предпочитаю вторую):

```
create table tab (
    bool1 number not null check (bool1 in (0,1)),
    bool2 varchar2 (5) not null, 
    constraint chk_tab_bool2 check (bool2 IN ('true','false'))
)
/

Table TAB created.
```